# Ruby On Rails pass form parameter from the View to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

i am pretty new to Ruby. Trying to get get an independent parameter 
sent via the link_to. Not working, any help would be appreciate.

The View is:

```
<%= number_field_tag :quantity %> 
<%= link_to "Add to basket", product_path(@product.permalink, :quantity), :method => :post %>
```

The controller:

```
def buy
  @product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink])
  @quantity = (params[:quantity]).to_i
  current_order.order_items.add_item(@product, @quantity)
  redirect_to product_path(@product.permalink), :notice => "Product has been added successfuly!"
end
```

Basically it is only transmitting the `nil` value for the `:quantity`, I do not know how to pass the actual value input by the user.

Comment: The View is: <%= number_field_tag :quantity %>

<%= link_to "Add to basket", product_path(@product.permalink, :quantity), :method => :post %>

Comment: You have a higher chance of getting an answer if you make it easy for us to understand your problem. Please format the question properly, the next time.